# Bayes rule and conditional independence

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, independence, bayes

I have two conditionally independent random variables $A$, $B$ such that 
$$
P(A,B\mid C) = P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C) .
$$
I have to find posterior formula $P(C \mid A,B)$.

My result with a straigthforward application of Bayes rule is
$$
P(C \mid A,B) = \frac{P(B\mid C)P(A\mid C)P(A)}{P(A\cap B)} .
$$
with few variants (e.g. get an intersection on numerator).

But I can't get the lecturer's solution that is
$$
\frac{P(B\mid C)P(C\mid A)}{P(B\mid A)} .
$$

Comment: In _your_ formula, what happens if you divide numerator and denominator by $P(A)$ so that in the numerator $P(A)$ disappears while the denominator becomes $P(A\cap B)/P(A)$?

Comment: Ha! Thanks a lot @DilipSarwate ! Since they're then both correct, is the lecturer one more common somehow?

Comment: Well, _your lecturer's answer differs from yours_ in that it has $P(C\mid A)$ while you have $P(A\mid C)$ so I am wondering which one of them is correct, or if one has a typographical error in it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your answer is incorrect.  A straight-forward application of Bayes' rule would be that

$P(C \mid A,B) = \dfrac{P(A,B\mid C) P(C)}{P(A,B)}= \dfrac{P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C) P(C)}{P(A,B)}$

After a little bit of simplification, you will get the professor's answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could also include the simplification that results in the "professor's answer"? I am curious to see how $\dfrac{P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C) P(C)}{P(A,B)}$ can be manipulated into $\dfrac{P(B\mid C)P(C\mid A)}{P(B\mid A)}$, or, assuming that there is a typo in the OP's statement, into $\dfrac{P(B\mid C)P(A\mid C)}{P(B\mid A)}$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Perhaps simplification was the wrong word? This was self-study, so I will outline the remaining steps.  Combine $P(A \mid C)$ with $P(C)$.  Then divide numerator and denominator by $P(A)$